# Jquery appendTo html to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, append

building a show your password with a caps lock warning on a form. But need to use appendTo so the HTML can be added to a pre-written shortcode.

Whenever the Html is added by appendTo the Javascript function can not find the added HTML.

code: https://codepen.io/edutize/pen/qBZXmOZ

```
<div class="memberium-form">

<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="https://traderonthestreet.com/wp-login.php" method="post">
  <input id="learndash-login-form" type="hidden" name="learndash-login-form" value="754942d3df">
  <p class="login-username">
    <label for="user_login"></label>
    <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" placeholder="Email *">
  </p>
  <p class="login-password">
    <label for="user_pass"></label>
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" placeholder="Password *">
  </p>
  
  <p class="login-submit">
    <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary" value="Login">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="https://traderonthestreet.com/wp-admin/">
  </p>
  
</form>
```

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("<span></span>").appendTo(".login-password").attr("toggle", "#user_pass").addClass("fa fa-fw 
    fa-eye field-icon toggle-password");
      $("<p>WARNING! Caps lock is ON.</p>").appendTo(".login-password").attr("id", "caps");    
    });


    $(".toggle-password").click(function() {

      $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
      var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
      if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
        input.attr("type", "text");
      } else {
        input.attr("type", "password");
      }
    });


    var input = document.getElementById("user_pass");
    var text = document.getElementById("caps");
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {

    if (event.getModifierState("CapsLock")) {
        text.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        text.style.display = "none"
      }
    });
```

Comment: The logic that adds the elements is inside a document ready.  The logic that tries to bind on the elements created in the document ready, is not in a document ready.  Thus, problem.  The element will not exist yet.

Comment: You're adding the `toggle` attribute to the span that's being appended, not the p you appended it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're generating elements inside document ready which usually is initiated later than when the JS is loaded. When the `$(".toggle-password").click(function()` event listener is attached to `.toggle-password`, `#caps` doesn't exists yet.

Either moving the event listener into the document ready after the `#caps` element is created or moving the `#caps` element creation outside the document ready will work.

```js
// Jquery appendTo capslock message and eye icons html

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("<span></span>").appendTo(".login-password").attr("toggle", "user_pass").addClass("fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password");
  $("<p>WARNING! Caps lock is ON.</p>").appendTo(".login-password").attr("id", "caps");    
  
  // toggle between classes and change attribute type
$(".toggle-password").click(function() {

  $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
  var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
  if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
    input.attr("type", "text");
  } else {
    input.attr("type", "password");
  }
});

// capslock function change style from display none to block
var input = document.getElementById("user_pass");
var text = document.getElementById("caps");
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {

if (event.getModifierState("CapsLock")) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none"
  }
});

});
```

```css
.login-username input[type=text] {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: vertical;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: .1s;
}
.login-username input[type=text]:hover {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
transform: scale(1.01);
    
}

.login-password input[type=password] {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: vertical;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: .1s;
}
.login-password input[type=password]:hover {
    
       background-color: #e6e6e6;
transform: scale(1.01);
    
    
}

.login-password input[type=text] {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: vertical;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: .1s;
}
.login-password input[type=text]:hover {
    
       background-color: #e6e6e6;
transform: scale(1.01);
    
    
}

#caps {
  display: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  color: red;
}

.field-icon {
  margin-left: 72.5%;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -40px;
  color: #8A8A8A;
}
    
.login-submit input[type=submit] {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #24af61;
  border: #24af61;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  border-width: 1.5px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.login-submit input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.11);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.11);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.11);
transform: scale(1.05);
color: #24af61;
border-style: solid;
border: #24af61;
border-width: 1.5px;
border-radius: 15px;
}

  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .login-password input[type=password] , .login-username input[type=text] , .login-submit input[type=submit] {
    width: 75%;
  }
  
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .field-icon {
    margin-left: 82%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="memberium-form">

    <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="https://traderonthestreet.com/wp-login.php" method="post">
      <input id="learndash-login-form" type="hidden" name="learndash-login-form" value="754942d3df">
      <p class="login-username">
        <label for="user_login"></label>
        <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" placeholder="Email *">
      </p>
      <p class="login-password">
        <label for="user_pass"></label>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" placeholder="Password *">
<!--         html thats being added by jquery appendTo -->
<!--         <span toggle="#user_pass" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
        <p id="caps">WARNING! Caps lock is ON.</p> -->
      </p>
      
      <p class="login-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary" value="Login">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="https://traderonthestreet.com/wp-admin/">
      </p>
      
    </form>
    
</div>
```